# Creating while and for loops to see if is greater, equal to,or less than B. Then printing the result

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I want to use while or/and for loops to compare the value of a and b (entered by user) then print which is bigger, and if either are equal to zero the loop stops.

I have tried to write the code for it with no luck as I don't understand while and for loops.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Set31 {



    public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int a = 1;
            int b = 4;

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            while (a < b && a!=0 && b!=0)
            {

                System.out.println("b is bigger than a");

                System.out.print("enter a ");
                a = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("enter b ");
                b = input.nextInt();
            }   

            while (a > b && a!=0 && b!=0)
            {

                System.out.println("a is bigger than b");

                System.out.print("enter a ");
                a = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("enter b ");
                b = input.nextInt();
        }
            while (a == b && a!=0 && b!=0)
            {
                System.out.println("a is equal to b");

                System.out.print("enter a ");
                a = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("enter b ");
                b = input.nextInt();
            }


    }


}
```

The loop stops after I run the program after about 1-4 times that I enter the input numbers.

Comment: I will give you a hint.. :) While this condition is true to make the condition run in a loop and inside this big while you could do your check ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no main loop surrounding your code. The following around all your while loops should do the trick.

```java
while(a!=0 && b!=0) {
...
}
```

So if one of your inputs is zero, no loop will continue and the routine finished.
Otherwise one of your other three loops will handle the input, asking for new input and then start over again by the main loop.

Comment: You really only need a single loop for this though, your current 3 `while` loops are unneeded, only one you need is the one thinkingeye has mentioned.

Comment: But how would you do the comparision if you want only use while and for loops?

Comment: Using an `if` statement?

Comment: I know, but the task was written to just use while and for loops.

Comment: I don't see where the task says they can ONLY use loops to do this.  Just they need to use a loop in their code somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `do-while` loop for this which will always execute at least one time, and then exit when either `b` or `a` are equal to 0:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")  //Used to remove unclosed warning
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a;
    int b;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter value for a: ");
        a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter value for b: ");
        b = input.nextInt();

        if (a < b) {
            System.out.println("a is less than b");
        }
        else if (a > b) {
            System.out.println("a is greater than b");
        }
        else if (a == b) {
            System.out.println("a is equal to b");
        }
    } while (a != 0 && b != 0);

    System.out.println("Loop has finished!");
}
```

**Example Run:**

```
Enter value for a: 
1
Enter value for b: 
3
a is less than b
Enter value for a: 
3
Enter value for b: 
5
a is less than b
Enter value for a: 
0
Enter value for b: 
1
a is less than b
Loop has finished!
```

You do not need to use a `while` loop to check for every condition, and can rather use a simple `if` and `if else` statement to check each outer loop for which value is greater.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to editing the loop condition, you can exit mid-loop using a `break` statement to alter control flow. This can be done like so:

```
int a;
int b;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a: ");
    a = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter b: ");
    b = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    if(a == 0 || b == 0) break;
    String comparison = (a > b) ? "is bigger than" : (a < b) ? "is less than" : "is equal to";
    System.out.println("a "+comparison+" b");
}
String exitReason = (a == 0 && b == 0) ? "a and b are" : (a == 0) ? "a is" : "b is";
System.out.println("Exited because "+exitReason+" equal to zero");
```

Comment: i think i got the logic behind what you mean though i did not reach this level. thanks anyway.

Comment: @AbdullahAliAl-nemer No problem, as long as it helps :)